# Sort odd numbers in Array of even and odd numbers

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, integer

I need to sort the odd numbers in the inputted array. So we do nothing with the even numbers in the array but we sort the odd numbers in ascending order

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(sortArray(new int[]{1, 5, 2, 7, 3}));
}
public static int[] sortArray(int[] array) {
    List<Integer> odds = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int elmnt : array) {
        if (elmnt % 2 != 0) {
            odds.add(elmnt);
        }
    }
    odds.stream().sorted();
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (array[i] %2 != 0){
            for (int j = 0; j < odds.size(); j++) {
                array[i] = odds.get(j);
            }
        }
    }
    return array;
}
```

in this example, the array should turn into:
[1, 3, 2, 5, 7]

how can I do this?

Comment: Do you know how to sort an array normally? Do you know how to identify an odd number? What did you try? Show at least your code for sorting the array completely please, as an [mre]. Then describe what has you stuck with the other requirements. Doing this will avoid the impression that you just hope for somebody to do your work for you. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Comment: Done. Here is what I have right now ^

Comment: And what has you now stuck? What does not work as desired?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a nifty solution using the `Stream` API.

```
public static int[] sortOdds(int[] a) {
    var sortedOdds = Arrays.stream(a).filter(v -> v % 2 == 1).sorted().toArray();
    for (int i = 0, s = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        if (a[i] % 2 == 1) {
            a[i] = sortedOdds[s];
            s++;
        }
    }
    return a; // A return here is kind of redundant but whatever.
}
```

However, as @Yunnosch mentioned, this really isnt a good question for stack overflow. This feels like a homework question, and if it is I doubt any professor would accept the solution above since it uses `sorted()` instead of actually implementing a sorting algorithm.

Comment: Great thanks. Can you explain simply why "s" is needed and why I couldn't just write a[i] = sortedOdds[i]; ? I get Index 4 out of bounds for length 4 when I use sortedOdds[i] but I'm not quite sure why because it seems like s is always = to i

Comment: @NoahSolomon This is because ```sortedOdds``` only contains the odd values from ```a```. ```a``` and ```sortedOdds``` have different lengths, and their indexes wont match up. We need ```s``` as a separate iterator value so keep track of our index in ```sortedOdds```. Notice how ```s``` is only incremented when an odd value is found and replaced.

Comment: There we go thank you. I did not notice it was incremented inside the if statement. So if s++ was outside of the if statement then it would hit the index length exceeded error

Answer (score 1):

- First, write a sort routine to sort normally in ascending order.  If you don't know how to do that, you can do a web search for `bubble sort`, `selection sort`, etc. but the first two are easily implemented.
- Once you have that working, simply modify the sort to work only on odd numbers.

It is not necessary to presort any or all of the array and then manipulate the values afterwards (although the cost of filtering and and sorting a smaller array in preparation may have performance benefits over sorting a larger array)